# SQLAlchemy Many-To-One relation query filter for column in list

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have following models defined:

```
class Attribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = "attributes"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    data_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("data.art_no"))
    name = Column(VARCHAR(500), index=True)

    data = relationship("Data", back_populates="attributes_rel")


class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    art_no = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    multiplier = Column(Float)
    attributes_rel = relationship("Attribute", back_populates="data", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

@property
def attributes(self):
    return [attribute.name for attribute in self.attributes_rel]
```

If I query for `Data` rows, I get this rows (only attributes property:

```
#1 ['attributeX', 'attributeY']
#2 ['attributeZ']
#3 ['attributeX', 'attributeZ']
```

I want to do following thing now:

I have this list `['attributeX']` and I want to query my data and only get the `Data` rows back, which has the `'attributeX'` attribute.
If I have this list `['attributeX', 'attributeZ']`, I want to query my data and only get the `Data` rows back, which has the `'attributeX'` **AND** `'attributeZ'` attribute.

How can I do the queries?

I tried `.filter(models.Data.attributes_rel.any(models.Attribute.name.in_(attributesList)))` which returns all rows which has any of the attribute from `attributesList` .... but I want only get the `models.Data` rows which has **exactly** the attributes from the list (or even others, too, but at least the ones from the list)

Optical sample of my issue:

[image]

This three attributes are associated to `Data` rows. I have set `attributeList=['Test2','Test3']` ... but also the last row is returned .. because it has attribute `Test3` but it should not be returned because it has not `Test2` ... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_` will basically do `any of the attributes is present`, whereas what you want is `ALL attributes are present`.

To achieve this, just add filter for each attribute name separately:

```
q = session.query(Data)
for attr in attributesList:
    q = q.filter(Data.attributes_rel.any(Attribute.name == attr))
```